# YA book - kids detective / mystery book where they travel into the computer / web

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, computers

I’m searching for a YA book I read back in primary school in Australia in the 1990s (so I’m a bit fuzzy on details).
The book itself had a metallic silver cover. I remember it being a computer mystery / detective type story with a group of maybe 2-3 school aged kids. They travelled between the real world and places on the web to find various people / characters (who were named after computer components).

One part I remember is they travelled to a type of club / nightclub and had to meet with a character called Seedy ROM.

I know I’m short on details and it’s a long shot. I have searched the forum here and googled endless combinations with no luck. It may have been part of the Scholastic brand of books, which is a company in Australia that sells books directly to parents in schools.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did they visit the web in VR, or just using real life computers?

Comment: *"and had to meet with a character called Seedy ROM"* - Are you sure this wasn't [Seedy RON](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oPFiuCwUcMU)? *(He's got a compact disc player!)*

Comment: Some similarities to [*The Mummy Monster Game*](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TheMummyMonsterGame). Inc. being originally published in Australia in the 1990s, and the three school-aged children.

Comment: Another possibility - ["The Glitch: A Computer Fantasy"](https://ronaldkidd.com/Novels/Genre-Novels/ArtMID/424/ArticleID/116/The-Glitch-A-Computer-Fantasy) by Ronald Kidd? There are some page scans at [this eBay listing](https://www.ebay.com/itm/255904392215)

Comment: @Showsni - I believe they visited using real life computers.